# Get past Google lock

Tags: factory-reset

I have a Samsung Galaxy J3 prime.it was factory reset and now won't let me log in to the internet. I don't have the Google account email address

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the new Account Protection on android devices above 4.4 ( i think )

It's designed to stop someone stealing your device and then just doing a factory reset to basically have a new device.

After a factory reset, you'll need to confirm ownership of the device by logging into Google with a previously linked account.

Only idiot's still think that device theft is an option when trying to get a new device.

Some second-hand stores, fail to properly reset device's because they don't ask you to remove all of your linked accounts first !!! ...

To stop Account Protection on Factory Reset, you'll need to REMOVE ALL accounts on the device !!

You'll know it's ready for a proper reset when you try to remove the last google account, it'll say that device security features will be disabled if you remove the only linked account... Once you accept the removal of the last linked account, it'll be ok for a factory reset !!